# How to pass an argument to a method called in a NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, arguments, nstimer, nsinvocation

I have a timer calling a method but this method takes one paramether:

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

should be

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval target:self selector:@selector(timer:game) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

now this syntax doesn't seems to be right. I tried with NSInvocation but I got some problems:

```
timerInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
        [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(timer:game)]];

theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval
        invocation:timerInvocation
        repeats:YES];
```

How should I use Invocation?

Answer (score 11):

Given this definition:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
   ...
}
```

You then need to use `@selector(timerFired:)` (that's the method name without any spaces or argument names, but including the colons). The object you want to pass (`game` ?) is passed via the `userInfo:` part:

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval 
                                            target:self 
                                          selector:@selector(timerFired:) 
                                         userInfo:game
                                          repeats:YES];
```

In your timer method, you can then access this object via the timer object's `userInfo` method:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    Game *game = [timer userInfo];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @DarkDust points out, `NSTimer` expects its target method to have a particular signature. If for some reason you can't conform to that, you can instead use an `NSInvocation` as you suggest, but in that case you need to fully initialise it with the selector, target and arguments. Eg:

```
timerInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                   [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(methodWithArg1:and2:)]];

// configure invocation
[timerInvocation setSelector:@selector(methodWithArg1:and2:)];
[timerInvocation setTarget:self];
[timerInvocation setArgument:&arg1 atIndex:2];   // argument indexing is offset by 2 hidden args
[timerInvocation setArgument:&arg2 atIndex:3];

theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval
                                        invocation:timerInvocation
                                           repeats:YES];
```

Calling `invocationWithMethodSignature` on its own doesn't do all that, it just creates an object that is able to be filled in in the right manner.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `NSDictionary` with named objects (like `myParamName => myObject`) through `userInfo` parameter like this

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationInterval 
                                            target:self 
                                          selector:@selector(timer:) 
                                          userInfo:@{@"myParamName" : myObject} 
                                           repeats:YES];
```

Then in `timer:` method:

```
- (void)timer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    id myObject = timer.userInfo[@"myParamName"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you need to pass several objects that's the way to go. But if it's just a single object you don't need to encapsulate it into a dictionary.

Comment: True. I've just seen notifications use userInfo dictionaries so thought to keep consistency.