# Passing a method with an argument to NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can't figure out how to using a method that has an argument with `NSTimer`. The code i'm using is below - with the idea being a label is sent to the first method where it is turned red and then after a second the second method is called and the label is turned black.

```
-(void) highlightWord:(UILabel *)label
{
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    //[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(unhighlightWord:label) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) unhighlightWord:(UILabel *)label {
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];

}
```

With the code like this, Xcode tells me: `Expected ":"` after`@selector(unhighlightWord:label`. If i add in the ":" i get an `unrecognized selector` message at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an argument to a method called in a NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166171/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-method-called-in-a-nstimer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector for the timer method takes one argument which is the timer itself (you don't specify any argument in the selector -- it should just be @selector(unhighlightWord:)). So, you need to have an ivar or property that points to your label, and use that in your method, rather than trying to pass the label as an argument.

```
-(void) highlightWord:(UILabel *)label
{
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    self.myLabel = label; // myLabel is a property
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(unhighlightWord:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void) unhighlightWord:(NSTimer *) aTimer {
    self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];

}
```

Comment: When you setup the timer, you can provide a "userInfo" object (which can be essentially anything), then access it in the timer callback by asking the timer for its userInfo object.

Comment: @DavidH, yes, I was just going to update my answer to include that -- that's really the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @DavidH. If you post up just that i can accept it as the answer

Comment: Sorry, no, you missed my point - this answer is the answer to select! I just added a slight nuance. Please give the original poster the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works fine, but another (and probably better) solution is to just pass the label to with the timer's `userData`:

```
-(void) highlightWord:(UILabel *)label
{
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:235 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(unhighlightWord:) userInfo:label repeats:NO];

}

- (void)unhighlightWord:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    if ([aTimer.userData isKindOfClass[UILabel class]]) {
        ((UILabel *)aTimer.userData).textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    }
    // can do other checks for different objects (buttons, dictionaries, switches, etc...)
}
```

This is extremely nice for lose code, if you want to use this same method/mechanism for a different label (or even other objects like buttons) you could do so, assuming you had the correct checks in place.

You can also pass a dictionary in for `userData` if you want other information:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(unhighlightWord:) userInfo:@{@"sender": label, @"otherData", @"some important value"} repeats:NO];
```

Then in your receiving method you can access the data as you would with a normal dictionary:

```
if ([aTimer.userData isKindOfClass[NSDictioanry class]]) {
    // do something
}
```