# NSTimer + NSInvocation causing crash on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nstimer, nsinvocation

I'm running into a crash when using `+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats]` on iOS 7. The code is straightforward enough; here is the copy paste (with variable renames) in its entirety.

```
SEL selector = @selector(callback);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
```

When the timer fires, my app crashes with the following stack trace:

[image]

I thought that maybe one of the variables was no longer retained (even though NSTimer's documentation mentions that it retains all referenced parameters), so I strongly retained all of the variables to `self`. Unfortunately, the crash persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing this line  `[self.invocation setSelector:selector];`

This will work

```
SEL selector = @selector(callback);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:selector];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];

- (void)callback
{
    NSLog(@"triggered");
}
```

**Output:**

```
triggered
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I should have read the documentation a bit more closely. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166561/2073396) seems to suggest you need to call setSelector: on the invocation in addition to init-ing it with the signature.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is usually common courtesy (if it isn't a rule somewhere) to let the OP know if his question is a duplicate. The answer that you post should be your own. That way if the answer that you link works, he can up-vote that answer and the credit can go to the correct person.

Comment: What does OP stand for? And how should I let her know? Comment on the question?

Comment: OP is Original Post (or poster). And you are correct, a comment on the question. I am not trying to discourage you from answering, or even telling you to delete this answer. Just a pointer with regards to answering questions :)

Comment: Appreciate it - I've used SO as long as it has been around, but this is my first time posting anything :)

Comment: well played, on both sides.